# Deciding which class method to be called according to class initiatiation parameters

Tags: python, class-method

I struggled to create a descriptive title, but my challenge is the following:

In my Python application, I have a communication module which previously just used one transport type, serial. Now I also want it to include another transport layer, called RTT. 
My class `COM` contains methods like `connect`, `send`, `read`, `log` etc. Now I need two different versions of all these methods, and I want have it so that which methods being called is decided upon class instantiation.

E.g `comlink = COM('RTT')` will use the set of send, read, connect which is specific to the RTT protocol and vice versa, without the need of creating an extra class and decide which class to use on a higher level.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't have subclasses and a `COM()`function that returns the correct subclass type? Because that is essentially what you are describing.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are also other, arguably better, ways to do it.

Comment: @HannesOvrén Well, I haven't thought of that solution, but surely that will be enough I guess. I don't have much experience with python, so could you write up a short example in the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given I fully support @Hannes Ovrén's comment and answer, here is another way to do it

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, protocol='SERIAL'):
        std_f = ('connect', 'send', 'read', 'log')
        protocols = ('RTT', 'SERIAL')
        if protocol not in protocols:
            print("Protocol not supported!")
            raise Exception # your exception here

        prot_f = [getattr(self, name+'_'+protocol.lower()) for name in std_f]
        for f, new_f in zip(std_f, prot_f):
            setattr(self, f, new_f)

    def connect_serial(self, hostname):
        print('I am serial connect', hostname)
    def send_serial(self, hostname):
        print('I am serial send', hostname)
    def read_serial(self, hostname):
        print('I am serial read', hostname)
    def log_serial(self, hostname):
        print('I am serial log', hostname)

    def connect_rtt(self, hostname):
        print('I am RTT connect', hostname)
    def send_rtt(self, hostname):
        print('I am RTT send', hostname)
    def read_rtt(self, hostname):
        print('I am RTT read', hostname)
    def log_rtt(self, hostname):
        print('I am RTT log', hostname)
```

Basically it assigns the name of the standard functions when the class is instantiated, based on the given protocol

```
>>> from two_types_of_methods import A
>>> a=A('RTT')
>>> a.connect('myserv.com')
I am RTT connect myserv.com
>>> a.send('myserv.com')
I am RTT send myserv.com
>>> a.read('myserv.com')
I am RTT read myserv.com
>>> a.log('myserv.com')
I am RTT log myserv.com
>>> b=A()
>>> b.connect('myserv.com')
I am serial connect myserv.com
>>> b.send('myserv.com')
I am serial send myserv.com
>>> b.read('myserv.com')
I am serial read myserv.com
>>> b.log('myserv.com')
I am serial log myserv.com
```

Comment: But wouldn't this only work for one type of method, in this case the connect method?

Comment: that was an example. I have updated the answer, you lazy bee ;)

Comment: Haha, thank you so much! I would "never" have figured out this one `prot_f = [getattr(self, name+'_'+protocol.lower()) for name in std_f]` by myself so really appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a prime example of why subclassing should be the preferred option in this case. (solid answer otherwise though!) :)

Comment: @HannesOvrén I agree 100%. I would go for your solution (i.e. a class factory), using an ABC to define the interface

Answer (score 2):

Let `COM()` be a function that returns the correct class instance.
E.g.

```
def COM(ctype):
    try:
        klass = {
            'RTT' : ComRTT,
            'serial' : ComSerial}[ctype]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError("Invalid connection class: {}".format(ctype))
    instance = klass()
    return instance

>>> com = COM('RTT')
```

You could also do this as a class method to a base class.

```
class Communication:
    @classmethod
    def from_type(cls, ctype):
        try:
            klass = {
                'RTT' : ComRTT,
                'serial' : ComSerial}[ctype]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("Invalid connection class: {}".format(ctype))
    return klass()

>>> com = Communication.from_type('RTT')
```

The result and pattern is the same, but the latter might be preferable since it (arguably) makes it more clear that it has something to do with the `Communication` class(es).

Comment: Excellent answer. It solves my problem but the accepted one answers the question at hand. This seems more clear though, so my fault I didn't know this before asking.